# The content on the A2 Hosting server is not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

Who has worked with the A2 Hosting service, tell me, I uploaded the files of my React project to public_html, and for some reason the content on my site that should be rendered does not render. Here are my files:

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'; 

import './index.css';

window.onload = () => {
  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "https://famfindtree.com/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "genealogy-commercial-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://famfindtree.com",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bingmaps": "^2.0.3",
    "bingmaps-react": "^1.2.10",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:js": "eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>FamFindTree</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function (l) {
        if (l.search[1] === '/') {
          var decoded = l.search
            .slice(1)
            .split('&')
            .map(function (s) {
              return s.replace(/~and~/g, '&');
            })
            .join('?');
          window.history.replaceState(
            null,
            null,
            l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash
          );
        }
      })(window.location);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think maybe there is a problem with the paths or something like that, because there are no errors in the console, and in general everything works fine, but this part of the react does not work.

Comment: You aren't even including any .js file. Browsers can't read your .js (actually ,jsx) file anyway. Please read on [Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)